# what this line of code mean ? $channel =<<<_XML_;

Tags: php, xml

```
$channel =<<<_XML_;
```

1. what is meaning of above statement ?
2. Is *XML* predefined variable ?
3. What is the meaning of <<<

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is called a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). It's very convenient to enter long (usually multiline) strings without having to mess around with escaping etc.